# Guessing the value of $n$

Tags: combinatorics

$A$ and $B$ play game, $A$ choose $n$ where $n \in \{1, 2,\ldots 1001\}=S$.

$B$ has to guess the value of $n$ by choosing a number of subsets of $S$, then $A$ will tell $B$ the number of subsets $B$ choose that contain $n$.

Do the same operation for $3$ times, let $k_1, k_2, k_3$ be the number of subsets that $B$ choose in the $1^{st}, 2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ time respectively.

Find the minimum possible value of $ k_1 + k_2+ k_3$ such that $B$ always makes a correct guess.

My thought :

The $1^{st}$ time, $B$ choose $\{1\},  \{1,2\},  \{1, 2, 3\}, \ldots, \{1, 2, 3, \dots, 334\}$.

If $A$ says $334$, then $n=1$.

If $A$ says $1$, then $n=334$.

If $A$ says $0$, then $n\not\in \{1, 2, 3, \dots, 334\}$.

The $2^{nd}$ time, $B$ choose $\{335\},  \{335, 336\},\ldots, \{335, 336, 337 \dots, 671\}$.

The $3^{rd}$ time, $B$ choose $\{672\},  \{672, 673\},\ldots, \{672, 673, 674 \dots, 1001\}$.

Comment: What's the advantage of splitting those guesses into three stages?  You could just do $(1),(1,2), \cdots, (1,\cdots, 1001)$ on your first guess.  You can do better by, say, first guessing the multiples of three (one subset), then  all those of the form $(3k+1)$, (another subset) and then, if you have learned that the true number is $3k+2$ say, guess $(2),(2,5), (2,5,8), \dots, (2, 5, \cdots, 1001)$.  Not sure that's optimal though.

Comment: For that matter, you can improve your method directly, by first guessing $(1,\cdots, 334)$ then (if necessary) $(335, \cdots, 671)$ and then once you know which third the value is in, use your method in that third.  Same count as my method.

Comment: @lulu. I split the guesses into 3 steps because, if B makes a correct guess in the first time, $k_2$ and $k_3$ will be equal to zero. Not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Well, the problem appears to be asking for the worst case analysis.  For you, that's $1001$ since you have to assume the value will be in the worst third.  Definitely sub-optimal (the two, similar, methods I sketched come in around a third of that).  It would be different if they asked for the average analysis though even then your method is worse (average case is that the value is in the second third so you'd need to guess around $\frac 23\times 1001$.

Comment: I really don't know if my methods are optimal...in a hand-waving sort of way it feels pretty good.  I use the first two guesses to cut the problem down to one third the size and then I do it by force.  I do the reduction with only two guesses (which seems optimal) and then the force method needs at least $334$ possible answers so that seems optimal too.  Might be possible to turn that into a proof.

Comment: Oh, it's far from optimal.  You can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  If you are allowed to guess a subset multiple times you can get the congruence $\pmod 7$ in the first shot:  Guess {multiples of $7$}, {$7k+1$ } twice, and so on.  Then get congruence $\pmod {11}$ and $\pmod {13}$.  That's enough.  Maybe you can do the congruence more efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first round ask the six questions. 
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\{ i \mid i \equiv 1 \pmod 7 \} \\
\{ i \mid i \equiv 1  \pmod 7 \text{ or } i \equiv 2  \pmod 7 \} \\
\vdots \\
\{ i \mid i \equiv 1 \text{ or } 2 \text{ or }  3 \text{ or }  4 \text{ or } 5 \text{ or }  6\pmod 7  \} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

On the second round ask the $10$ questions 
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\{ i \mid i \equiv 1 \pmod {11} \} \\
\{ i \mid i \equiv 1 \text{ or } 2 \pmod {11} \} \\
\vdots \\
\{ i \mid i \equiv 1 \text{ or } 2 \text{ or } 3 \text{ or } 4 \cdots 10  \pmod {11} \} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

On the third round ask the $12$ questions 
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\{ i \mid i \equiv 1 \pmod {13} \} \\
\{ i \mid i \equiv 1 \text{ or } 2 \pmod {13} \} \\
\vdots \\
\{ i \mid i \equiv 1 \text{ or } 2 \text{ or } 3 \text{ or } 4 \cdots 12  \pmod {13} \} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

The value can be deduced using the Chinese remainder theorem. and the optimal value of $k_1+k_2+k_3$ is ...

Comment: Thank you. Is minimum  $k_1+k_2+k_3= 6+10+12=28$ correct ?

Comment: $28$ thats right. It still remains to show that there is not another value greater than $1001$ that can be expressed as the product of $3$ primes and giving a value $p_1+p_2+p_3 -3 < 28$.(See Arno's Answer)

Comment: I don't know how $p_1+p_2+p_3 -3 < 28$ and $(k_1+1)(k_2+1)(k_3+1) \geq 1001$ (or $p_1p_2p_3 \geq 1001$) are related ? Please give me details.

Comment: $k_i+1=p_i$. for $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: Did you mean, solve $p_1p_2p_3 \geq 1001$ and $p_1+p_2+p_3 -3 < 28$ to show that there is no answer lesser than 28 ?

Comment: Thats right. For example we would not do better if we replaced $1001$ by $1105$ although a similar sequence of questions would work.

Comment: By AM-GM, $$\left(\frac{p_1+p_2+p_3}{3}\right)^3 \geq p_1p_2p_3 \geq 1001$$

$$31^3 > (p_1+p_2+p_3)^3 \geq 27p_1p_2p_3 \geq 27,027 > 30^3$$

so, $31>p_1+p_2+p_3 > 30$, which is impossible. Hence $28$ is the minimum value. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 3):

A way to prove a lower bound here is by observing that in the $i$-th round, there are $k_i+1$ potential answers given by $B$. Thus, a strategy using $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$ sets in the first three rounds and then winning for sure needs to satisfy that $(k_1+1)(k_2+1)(k_3+1) \geq 1001$, since it needs to be able to distinguish all $1001$ potential choices from $S$.